# Java (Selenium WebDriver) - how to write compact code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, coding-style

I'm questioning myself on how to write more compact code and avoid  calling object in every line like this:

```
object.method1();
object.method2();
object.method3();
// etc
```

Recently I was surfing the net and found something like this:

```
object.method1();
.method2();
.method3();
// etc
```

So, how to achieve the style above without calling the object each time?

Sorry for such a basic question maybe, but Idk how it's named and how to google it.
Hope for your help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `object.method1().method2().method3()`

method1/2/3() should return 'this'?

You can check for builder design pattern in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `Fluent` pattern, also known as `Chain of invocation`.

In short: Your test is composed of high level steps and for each step/method you should know what it returns, if it doesn't navigate to another object then return the current instance (`this`), else return the next object.

e.g. login successful > account page, failed login > login page